# Remove parts of url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/a87ff.gif

how do I do a mod rewrite to change it to

http://website.com/a87ff

htaccess looks like this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# END WordPress


# BEGIN wtwp_cache
# END wtwp_cache

# BEGIN wtwp_security
# END wtwp_security
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have attempted so far?

Comment: I do not know where to even start :(

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z0-9-_]+)$
RewriteRule ^/? /wp-content/uploads/%1.gif [NC]
```

Now, TRY THIS one! But it's not tested yet, for I'm in mobile.   ((;   Unlike the second edition of this code.

Comment: This is not what the asker wants. Please note the omission of the `.gif` extension.

Comment: Please give a full explanation including the exact URLs that the asker wanted to rewrite and the exact URLs that he wants to copy.

Comment: The asker's question is pretty straight forward in my opinion. He/she would like to access `/wp-content/uploads/a87ff.gif` via `/a87ff`. Please see my answer.

Comment: Ah.. Oh, sadly, I didn't recognized that there's no <i>.gif</i> file extension on his/her question.

Comment: That won't work if the user ever decides to use pretty permalinks (where everything is routed through `index.php`), which is why I opted for the route whereby Apache checks to see if the image exists first. That way, any other rules (like permalink routing) can be inserted afterwards and they won't interfere with what the user wants for images.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect request `http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/a87ff.gif` to `http://website.com/a87ff`, you must capture the desired part and use it in the substitution

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.+?)\.gif$ /$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: @Virtlink I don't think so. OP might need the other way round too, but first he must redirect the client to the desired URL.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/uploads/%{REQUEST_URI}.gif -f
RewriteRule (.*) /wp-content/uploads/$1.gif [L]
```

Let's run through this so you understand what's happening:

**RewriteCond** - Using this condition, we are checking to see if the file requested does actually exist in the applicable folder. So, if you enter `/test-image` as the URI, it will check to see if `wp-content/uploads/test-image.gif` exists.

**RewriteRule** - Now, if the file does exist, we'll silently pass it to the actual file. In other words, we'll get Apache to load up the file that does exist, without changing the URI that is visible to the user.

**In your case:**

If we enter this:             `http://website.com/a87ff`

The server will load:     `http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/a87ff.gif`